# I want to keep a SlidingDrawer half-open all the time

Tags: android

I want to keep a SlidingDrawer half-open all the time. The user will be able to see the contents of a drawer and interact with it (touch, etc.) for the open portion. If the user want to, she can still slide it further and open it completely. How might I achieve this in Android?